# On fly colorizing of specific words in textarea elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: jsfiddle example color change]
How do websites such as [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) make certain attributes (such as in the CSS section) different colors like a modern text editor would?

For example, the **html** tag is a different color to the **braces** in the CSS section in the picture above.

I assume that it's done dynamically using some sort of JS. Could anyone point me towards a script which could automatically and on the fly change the color of certain words to fit a color scheme?

Comment: It's called *Syntax Highlighting* Use Goog. My suggestion? (among 100's) http://prismjs.com/

Comment: What you're looking for is described as syntax highlighting. I'm sure there is a JS implementation out there..

Comment: @MjrKusanagi you can bet there's one :)

Comment: The way it works, is they just wrap the text in styles spans and divs. e.g., from jsfiddle, `<pre><span class="cm-property cm-error">blah</span></pre>`

Comment: [Highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org/) is frequently used. More options in this [post](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-javascript-syntax-highlighting-scripts/)

Comment: Or simply: inspect the desired element using your favorite Debugging tool (FireBug, Developer Tools...) and should give you an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) site uses the [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) editor. This editor inserts

```
<span class="cm-property">elements</span>
```

to format the code.

Examples of such libraries include the ones mentioned above:

- [highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org/)
- [prism](http://prismjs.com/)

And for example:

- [google-code-prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)
- [jquery.syntax](http://www.codeotaku.com/projects/jquery-syntax/index.en)
- [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)